# Convert Bootstrap 2 to ASP

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am having trouble getting my bootstrap jquery to work when I turn it into a .asp page from HTML. Is there anything specific I need to place in my file to get the functionality to work? Here is my header:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 8]>       <html lang="en-us" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>          <html lang="en-us" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>          <html lang="en-us" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->  <html lang="en-us">    <!--<![endif]-->


<head>
    <title>Page Name</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>


<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#scrollspyHook" data-offset="250">
```

Here is my script:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap_modified.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/grid.js"></script>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {


    // Schedule tabs
    $("#scheduleTabs a, #planningTabs a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });


    // Animated jump links for main nav
    $("a.scrollLink").click(function() {

        var destination = $(this).attr("href");

        $("body, html").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(destination).offset().top-140
        }, 1000);

        return false;

    });


    // Animated/fixed navigation
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() == 0) {
            $("#header").stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                height: "auto"
            }, 1000);
            $("#header").css("position", "static");
            $("#header").css("z-index", "auto");

            $("#main-nav.nav-pills > li > a").css("line-height", "117px");
            $("#main-logo").stop().animate({
                width: "203px"
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $("#header").stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: "#000000",
                height: "70px"
            }, 1000);
            $("#header").css("position", "fixed");
            $("#header").css("z-index", "10000");

            $("#main-nav.nav-pills > li > a").css("line-height", "75px");
            $("#main-logo").stop().animate({
                width: "145px"
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    $('.link').tooltip()

    $('#myModal').modal(options)

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included .css files and .js files to the project in asp.net?

- Download Bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/) and extract zip file.
- Drag and drop css,js and font folders into your project.

Add these references in header.

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

- Download jQuery from [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js). (Copy all the text)
- Right click on js folder and add file name with **jquery-2.0.3.js**,
  open it and paste all coped text in jQuery site.

Add this to the head.

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

Now it will work fine.If you want add links to other files also.